# Why do dropzone options fail to load?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, dropzone.js

I have a dropzone on my view and would like to set some options to force the files to be .zip. I also need to allow for these files to be bigger and get some information when it returns. The options don't seem to be loading for me and quecomplete never gets hit.

Edit.cshtml:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-8">
    <form asp-action="UploadFiles" class="dropzone" id="versionFiles"> 
    </form>
  </div>
</div>


@section Scripts {
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Dropzone.options.versionFiles = {
            acceptedFiles: ".zip",
            maxFileSize: 2048,
            timeout: 600000,
            init: function () {
                this.on("queuecomplete", function (file, response) {
                    console.log(file);
                })
            }
        };

    })
</script>
}
```

Edit: Fixed timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid configuring options for Dropzone inside `document.ready(function(){ /* ... */ })`.

To fix the issue, change your code as below :

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    Dropzone.options.versionFiles = {
        acceptedFiles: ".zip",
        maxFileSize: 2048,
        timeout: 600000,
        init: function () {
            this.on("queuecomplete", function (file, response) {
                console.log("ssssssssssssss",file);
            })
        }
    };
});
```

**[Edit] :**

The reason is the `Dropzone.js` will automatically discover all form elements with the class dropzone and automatically attach itself to it. If you configure the options by `document.ready(function(){/.../})`, you cannot guarantee the options is set before dropzone takes effects.

If you do need to trigger after document is ready, you could use a programmatical way to assure the sequence:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;           // disable auto discover

$(document).ready(function () { 
    Dropzone.options.versionFiles = {
        acceptedFiles: ".zip",
        maxFileSize: 2048,
        timeout: 600000,
        init: function () {
            this.on("queuecomplete", function (file, response) {
                console.log("xyz...",file);
            })
        }
    };
    $("#versionFiles").dropzone({ });   // trigger it
});
```

Comment: This is what I did before, but my colleague said it wasn't working. Can you tell me why not to use document.ready? Several of the examples I have read are setting options there.

Comment: @RachelMartin I've updated my answer, both ways work fine for me.  If you have any other questions, feel free to let me know.